# How should i correct this error?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Sn = Sum[1/((k + 1)^2), {k, 1, n}]
SSn = Sum[Sn*Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, m}]
Limit[(1/(Fibonacci[m + 2] - 1))*SSn, m -> Infinity]
```

> Limit::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity Log[2]-2 Log[1+Sqrt[5]]+Log[3+Sqrt[5]] is equal to zero. Assuming it is. >>

Comment: Where did you encounter it? That will determine what the best workaround is.

Comment: Sn = Sum[1/((k + 1)^2), {k, 1, n}]

SSn = Sum[Sn*Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, m}]

Limit[(1/(Fibonacci[m + 2] - 1))*SSn, m -> Infinity]

Comment: I don't get this error. Could you provide details about your OS and Mathematica version?

Comment: I now see that version 9 generates this error, V10 doesn't though both don't return a result for the third expression.

Comment: MAC OS X x86 - MATHEMATICA 9

Comment: The text itself indicates this is not an error message; it is provided as information to the user and does not indicate that you made an error that can be corrected.

Comment: so, it is not possible to evaluate the result of this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's help Mathematica out a little... first, the term `Sn` has a nice closed form solution, and an even simpler limit

```
Limit[1/6 (-6 + π^2 - 6 PolyGamma[1, 2 + n]), n -> Infinity]

1/6 (-6 + π^2)
```

which is about 0.644934. Next, observe that the term `SSn` has two parts. Taking just the part that involves the sums of the Fibonacci series,

```
Sum[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, m}]

-1 + Fibonacci[2 + m]
```

Thus Sum[Fibonacci[n], {n, 0, m}]/(-1 + Fibonacci[2 + m]) is identically equal to 1 for all m. Now if we think of this sum as a series of all 1s, it is constant! Thus the product of the series `Sn` and the series $1$ have the same limit, which is `1/6 (-6 + π^2).